# Java Generic - Explict type arguments for constructor invocation

Tags: java, generics

I believe I can provide explicit type arguments for the class while invoking constructor with new operator, like this:

`MyClass<?> obj = new MyClass<Float>("test", 1);`

where MyClass is defined like this:

```
class MyClass<T>{
    <K, V> MyClass(K k, V v){        
}
```

I suppose in this case Float is assigned to type parameter T.
And for K & V compiler infers the type from actual arguments provided.

My doubt is how I can provide explicit type arguments for constructor?
I know for methods I can do like `obj.method<Integer, String>(1, "test");`

I wonder is this kind of explicit type arguments(for K&V; not for T) are possible with constructors.

Hoping somebody can clear this for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uhm, if your class accepts type parameters, they should all be declared in the class declaration. Why define only one if you need two anyway?

Comment: @fge: These are not the class's type parameters, but type parameters for the generic constructor (similar to type parameters for a generic method).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You give type arguments between `new` and class name:

```
MyClass<?> obj = new <String, Integer>MyClass<Float>("test", 1);
```

BTW, for methods you give type argument before method name:

```
obj.<Integer, String>method(1, "test");
```